# Discrete $\mathbb{Z}_p[K]$ module with no K invariants is Trivial

Tags: modules, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I read the following fact in a paper: If $K$ is a finite $p$ group and $M$ a discrete $\mathbb{Z}_p[K]$ module such that $M^K=0$ then $M=0$.

This seems obviously wrong to me, which leads me to believe I am not understanding the definitions correctly. The obvious counterexample is $K=M=\mathbb{F}_p$. In this case $M$ has no $K$ invariants and yet is not zero.

Actually this is not a counterexample at all, since to be a module we must consider the finite field acting on itself via multiplication, and therefore 1 is an invariant.

In general, the question boils down to showing under the circumstances any p-adic representation of a p group contains the trivial representation. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, say $K$ is cyclic of order $p$. How does $\mathbb{F}_p[K]$ act on $\mathbb{F}_p$ in that case?

Comment: K will act by addition, i.e. $k \cdot m = k+m$, so the group algebra will act by extending this action linearly with the coefficients. Does this give an action?

Comment: You do not have $K$ acting linearly. Review the definition of a module. In particular, in any module over a group algebra, the module's zero element will be a fixed point with respect to every element of the group.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to reflect this silly error I made!